# How to pinch off small harvests from thyme plants?

Tags: pruning, herbs, harvesting

I am planning on harvesting my thyme. The thyme plants, 7 week-old since planting (seed pod going in a hydroponic system), are short and tiny compared to other herbs. I'd like to harvest some sprigs and still allow the rest to grow. Where/how should I cut? Should I pinch off whole stems where they branch off or should I keep some vital parts for regrowth?

**Edit:**

Please see photo below. Don't mind the basil behind. I know the thyme is being overpowered...

[image: Photo]

Comment: Pictures, please?

Comment: hydroponic for thyme? Thyme likes dry soils to get better and full scent. But as Stephie wrote: we need a picture to see how large, healthy and how many branches the plant has.  Few branches should be ok, but you used the word "harvest", so it seems you want to collect more than just for "today" meal. Is it right?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi It actually came as a seed pod with the amateurish hydroponic system I got from Amazon. Total rookie here, so I am learning to make it healthier. I actually just plan on harvesting for a curry dish I am cooking tonight. Two servings and recipe says "several sprigs"...

Comment: Cook here: If you took *all* of your thyme, that would be what “a few sprigs” are in a recipe. Especially if they are as thin and lanky as yours.

Comment: @Stephie I see. Any suggestion on how to make them healthier and lush?

Comment: Wait? Seven weeks from seed isn’t much. And I second @GiacomoCatenazzi: Thyme wants sun, warmth and not too much water for full aroma.

Comment: @Stephie Thank you both! I will be patient. Unfortunately there isn't much I can do about water. It came with the territory. I may be able to move the plant to a pot, but then I wouldn't have a place for it to get enough sun. Now the light source is an LED hood, part of the hydroponic system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily the answer to your question would be that you need to cut or pinch off all the long stems, immediately above a bud (or pair of leaves). Assuming that the longest of these stems are about 5" tall, I would leave 1.5" to 2" on the plant. The reason for doing this is to encourage the plant to develop more of a bushy habit, which will give you more, shorter, tender stems instead of fewer, longer and more woody stems. However in your case it looks like maybe the thyme is growing a bit lanky because it's being shaded by the basil, which could mean it won't grow bushy because it will always be seeking out the light.

As has been pointed out, thyme is a slightly odd companion for basil and other such annual herbs. It would be better grown alongside other perennial, oily herbs like rosemary and sage, which prefer dryer conditions.